# What are the best expository pieces related to the Van Hiele models?

Tags: reference-request, geometry, history

The [**Van Hiele model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Hiele_model) (wikipage) "is a theory that describes how students learn geometry."

I would appreciate further insights into the original model, later models that expanded or re-worked it, and the influence of the model on geometric thinking. To this end, my question is:

> What are the best expository pieces related to the Van Hiele models?

Comment: Wikipedia has a long article---[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Hiele_model)---with descriptions of the five levels (0,1,2,3,4).

Comment: Based on the lack of attention, the link in @JosephO'Rourke's comment, and the initial state of the question, I have overhauled it with a rather strong edit. Please revert the edit (or re-edit) if it gets away from the original intention!

Comment: I am not sure if I've understood the question correctly. But, [this](http://web.pdx.edu/~kheim/213%20Sp11/213%20Reading%201%20van%20Hiele%20-%20Begin%20With%20Play.pdf) piece of writing from Pierre Van Hiele himself, was one of the best I read after reading a lot of theoretical pieces about "their" work